# is it okay to have setState in callback of setState?

Tags: reactjs, state

```
addCourier=()=>{

const {courier}=this.state;

this.setState({
              counter:this.state.counter+1
              }),
               ()=>{
                this.setState({
                             courier:{...courier,"courier"+this.state.counter}
                             })
                   }


}
```

//Here courier is an array
//addCourier is called on button's Click event

Comment: I don't see why not

Comment: If you're asking whether it technically works, then yes it should. If you're asking whether you *should*, then no absolutely not

Comment: The callback function is called after state is updated, so you will end up rendering twice, rather than batching updates into a single render cycle.

Comment: @Jayce444 There are cases when using `setState` within the `setState` callback is warranted. It's a legal operation, and should not be considered otherwise if used properly. https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-chatterjee-8q10i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @lux I don't see an example of using the callback in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) but it does say: `Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.` Do you have a valid usecase to use the callback?

Comment: @lux whether it's "legal" or not isn't the best argument path to take. I mean yes, there may be a tiny handful of niche situation where it makes sense, but 99.99% of the time, you shouldn't be doing it. And particularly for newer users, doing that is a sign that you're doing something wrong elsewhere, or engaging in anti-patterns

Comment: @HMR I linked a naive example to codesandbox. You can use lifecycle methods for sure; and in OP's case, `prevState` most likely should have been used. I just have a thing against stating absolutes.

Comment: @lux I understand there should not be an absolute but that example does not show a valid reason to use the callback. The documentation even states that `If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead` but even then I think it would be better to pre calculate the state and set it once. In a recursively running timer you would need to know the previous state (cannot calculate new state once) but then according to the documentation you should prefer using updater function.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your example is that it's not even valid JavaScript but if it was then there is no reason to call a nested setState.

You can calculate the new value for counter first and use that new value multiple times to set the state once:

```
addCourier = () => {
  const { courier } = this.state;
  //calculate new value for counter
  const counter = this.state.counter + 1;
  this.setState({
    counter, //set new value for counter
    courier: {
      ...courier,
      //use new counter value
      other: 'courier' + counter,
    },
  });
};
```

The [documentation says](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

And:

> If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
});
```

But I think it's best to just calculate all state changes before setting the state and would be curious to see a valid usecase where you either need the callback or the updater function.